# Spring MVC, Ajax post JSON Object, 405 Method not allowed

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring-mvc

I need to send a String (or String array) as a JSON Object to the server but I keep getting this `405 Method not allowed` or the `Bad request` if I add the `csrf` parameter+token.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
var data = { 'info': $('#theData').html() }; // data is: <p> bla <strong>bla</strong> bla </p> 

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType : 'application/json',
    dataType : 'json',
    url: "editInfo", //  ?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}", // `Bad Request`
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(data){
        $('#responseMsg').html('YES!').show(200);
    },
    error: function(el) {
        var msg = 'Error ' + el.status + ': ' + el.statusText;
        $('#responseMsg').html(msg).show(200);
    }
});
```

This is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="editInfo", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers ="content-type=application/json")
public @ResponseBody String editInfo(
        @RequestBody Info info, 
        HttpServletRequest request) {

    // do stuff

    return "success";
}
```

The class `Info` has just 1 String named `info` with its getter and setter. Thou ideally I would like to capture just the String or String array, but whatever works without getting that `405 Method not allowed`

Comment: Hmm everything looks fine, I am not able to reproduce it - how would your url look like after ading CSRF token? Would you get 405 if you'd set static parameters (f.e. like url: "editInfo?param1=csrf_token") ?

Comment: OMG it works! I added the CSRF and I don't get the `Bad request` anymore, maybe because of the `headers` in the controllers which I didn't have when I was trying with the CSRF.
To answer your question the URL looks like this: `/editInfo?_csrf=8b1c698f-8086-4c3f-8d2e-913ebf93aff7`

Comment: @pzeszko you may add a response and I'll make it the correct answer =)

Comment: Thanks, Though, I don't think you need set headers in your controller method - it should work withoiut it.

Comment: You're right, it works without the `headers`... So I don't know why it wasn't working before...

Comment: So, in the end, what did you change exactly? Or maybe you didn't change anything at all? ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90129/discussion-between-pzeszko-and-esteban-santini).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm everything looks fine, I am not able to reproduce it - how would your url look like after ading CSRF token? Would you get 405 if you'd set static parameters (f.e. like url: "editInfo?param1=csrf_token") ?

---

After all it turned out that problem has probably occured because of controller method not being well defined, so it wasn't really jQuery issue.